# Как настроить изображение которое пришло с сервера в текстовой разметке, для UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

С сервера приходят данные к примеру `description`, в котором есть `html` разметки, эти разметки надо использовать для `UILabel`, это я делаю следующим образом:

```
extension UILabel {
func setHTMLFromString(htmlText: String) {
    let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: '-apple-system', 'SFUIDisplay-Light'; font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, htmlText) as String


    //process collection values
    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: modifiedFont.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
        documentAttributes: nil)


    self.attributedText = attrStr
}
```

}

вот для моего UILabel (descr) устанавливаю текст с разметками с помощью выше указанного расширения:

```
descr.setHTMLFromString(htmlText: descFull)
```

Все ок, разметки работают, так же приходит картинка в этих разметках следующим образом:

```
...<img src="http://new.site.ru/content/files/appimg/295-cifry-1.jpg" style="border:0px #000000;width:550px;height:357px;vertical-align:baseline"
```

Проблема в том что картинка не влазит в ширину экрана, вот как оно выглядит по дефолту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я сделал костыль, которые работает для текущей диагонали и текущих размеров, что не очень хорошо:

```
let descFull1 = descFull.replacingOccurrences(of: "width:550px;height:357px;", with: "width:40%;")
descr.setHTMLFromString(htmlText: descFull1)
```

вот как выглядит: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли что нибудь универсальное, чтобы работало во всех диагоналях (5,6,6+), в не зависимости что придет в `width:550px;height:357px;`?

Чтобы картинка входила в диагональ экрана и стояло аккуратно по центру?

Спасибо.

**АПДЕЙТ**

```
</div><div><br></div><div>По их мнению, ключевую роль в повышении спроса сыграли стабилизация экономики, отсутствие серьезных валютных колебаний и глобальные политические изменения в мире. По оценке JLL, активизация спроса распространится и на 2017 год и его совокупный объем сохранится га уровне 1–1,1 млн кв. м.</div><div><br></div><div><img src="/content/files/appimg/295-cifry-1.jpg" style="border:0px #000000;width:550px;height:357px;vertical-align:baseline" alt="Складская недвижимость 2016 год"><br></div><div style="text-align:right">Источник: CBRE</div><div style="text-align:right"><br></div><div>Рекордный объем сделок в Московском регионе
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD Под Ваш случай

```
let size = lblTest.frame.maxX
let styleForImg = "<head><style type=\"text/css\">img { width: \(size) !important; height: auto !important; }</style></head>"
let descFull1 = styleForImg + descFull
lblTest.setHTMLFromString(htmlText: descFull1)
```

---

Предложу костыль по мотивам Вашего, но условия выполнит:

```
let size = descr.frame.maxX
let styleForImg = "<head><style type=\"text/css\">img { width: \(size)px !important; height: auto !important; }</style>" //если нет таблицы стилей. Если есть, то перепишите чтоб дополнить ее
...
let descFull1 = descFull.replacingOccurrences(of: "<head>", with: styleForImg)
descr.setHTMLFromString(htmlText: descFull1)
```

Comment: Основное ж не дописал, размер по ширине UILabel берем :)

Comment: Работает, но только так реплейс(of: "width:550px;height:357px;", with: "width:\(size)px !important;height:auto !important;") но width и height могут поменяться или пробел появиться или еще что, и тогда не будет ничего работать (

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов можете привести полный пример html-строки? Текст/ссылки можете позаменять на ... . Интересно по тегам.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов интересная разметка. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Круто! работает, жаль конечно что я не совсем понял что вы сделали, это еще раз показывает, что не нужно  зацикливаться на одном языке, а быть все сторонне развитым...Еще раз спасибо.